# Different functionality in a single object situationally (Xna, Menusystems, and general C#)

Tags: c#, class, oop, dynamic, xna

I've been wondering a lot how to have an object act different situationally.
To clarify what I'm wondering:
I want to make a menusystem, and I want to have a "button" class. But the button should behave different depending on what kind of button it is.
One button may close to program, another may start the game, a third may enter settings.

(I was thinking of parsing methods as arguments, but then you still have to write a lot of different methods somewhere in your code)

How do you do this with OOP in mind? I could hardcode the very basic functions of a simple menu using enums and switchcases, but I would want to know if it could be avoided. 
I want to avoid things like delegates because games aren't eventbased in such fashion, and also switch-cases, large if/else statements because they are really ugly.

Is there a way to make objects behave like this?

What are other alternatives to making menus, trying to avoid the switch-cases for the commonly used enum. (Not disallowing enums)

Comment: First, this is definitely the right place to use events. Second, I absolutely hate delegates. Third, you should check out Reactive Extensions (Rx). http://rx.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to avoid things like delegates because games aren't eventbased in such fashion

Aren't they, though? A button click *is* an event, regardless of whether or not it's a game or a web application. It's by definition something happening that you'd like to react to, such as a button press. What happens when a button is clicked should be loosely coupled from the button in the UI, for the reasons you already encountered (large switch/if-elses are a pain) among others. A C# `event` field seems like the perfect fit, for this particular case anyway.

At some point, you create the settings button, somewhere, somehow. Why not wire up the event there? Something along the lines of:

```
class Button
{
  public Button(string label) {}
  public event Action Clicked;
}

class Program
{
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    var settingsButton = new Button("Settings");
    settingsButton.Clicked += () =>
    {
      // open settings view
    };
  }
}
```

I'd avoid things like inheritance for this problem as it adds unnecessary complexity for the wrong reasons. You should (probably) use inheritance if the overriding class changes or supplements the behavior of the class it extends (a logical progression would be `object` extended by `Component` extended by `Button` extended by `ToggleButton`) but not to create a class hierarchy that's very much tied to how your UI is built up. If you change settings access to a dropdown menu instead of a button press, you don't want to be tied to a `SettingsButton` class; you want to be simply able to change which event triggers the desired behavior, in this case pulling down the dropdown menu.

Comment: @Pontus, This methodology does not violate the common paradigm that Xna input is looped based rather than event based. The reason is that to get to Julian's event code in, say, the `settingsButton.Clicked()`, you would first poll the keyboardState, mouseState, or controllerState in your update loop and if your conditions are right, raise (call) the event yourself. And just so you know, this still uses delegates, it just hides them behind the event & Action keywords.... but that's ok, nothing to worry about in terms of GC affecting perf as long as all is created (new(ed)) during initialization

Comment: during initialization as opposed to during the game loop